# Angular - How to configure or import StoreDevtoolsModule at runtime or is there way to load json file before imports in app.module?

Tags: angular, runtime, environment, ngrx-store

I am working with Angular 13.3.2 and using ngrx store and importing StoreDevtoolsModule in app.module.ts file like

```
imports: [
.... other imports
StoreModule.forRoot({root: appReducer}),
EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
  name: 'Homegenius DevTools',
  maxAge: 25,
  logOnly: environment.isProduction
})
```

Now I want to remove dependecies of environment files and want to keep all configurations in config.json file to follow build once and deploy for multiple environments
We are using Ba,boo and octopus so after build and before deployment we are replacing config.json values to particular environment values.

So I modified above code like

```
import config from  "../assets/configs/config.json";

... other code
StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
  name: 'Test DevTools',
  maxAge: 25,
  logOnly: config.isProduction
})
```

But the problem is its considering value(config.isProduction) at compile time not after replacing config.json file.
Is there any solution to configure 'logOnly' property at runtime or import this module at runtime?

So far I have tried is created app.config.ts and reading config.json file before app initialize

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AppConfig {
   static settings: IAppConfig;
   http: HttpClient;

constructor(private readonly httpHandler: HttpBackend) {
    this.http = new HttpClient(httpHandler)
}
loadAppSettings() {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    const jsonFile = `assets/configs/config.json`;
    return this.http
      .get<IAppConfig>(jsonFile)
      .toPromise()
      .then(appSettings => {
        AppConfig.settings = appSettings;
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }  
}
```

And in app.module.ts

```
function appSettingsLoader(appSettingsService: AppConfig): any {
  return () => appSettingsService.loadAppSettings();
}
providers: [
  AppConfig,
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: appSettingsLoader,
    deps: [AppConfig],
    multi: true
  }
```

I am able to use Appconfig.settings (which has all configurtion values) at all other places in application but while importing module it is undefined as app initializer will execute after imports.